# call struts action from jquery - need help on how to make struts call and define struts action

Tags: jquery, struts2

I am fairly new to struts so I need to apologize for my lack of understanding. I am trying to execute a struts action that does an update on my database using jquery and need some guidance on how to do it. I have had a crack at it but it's not right.

I have a jquery dialog in my jsp(see below). You can see that on click of the button in this dialog I call a function named myAjaxCall()...

```
<s:div id="dialog-form" title="Update" style="display:none">
<s:form id="dform" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <s:textfield  name="strid" id="strid" label="Store" readonly="true"  />
    <s:textfield  name="strName" id="strName" label="Store Name" readonly="true" />
    <s:textfield  name="businessDt" id="businessDt" label="Business Date" readonly="true"  />
    <s:textfield  name="openingtime" id="openingtime"  label="Opening time(EST)" />
    <s:textfield  name="closingtime" id="closingtime"  label="Closing time(EST)" />
    <s:textfield  name="reason" id="reason" label="Reason" />
    <s:url id="ajaxDialog" value="/storeCurrentStatusDialog.action"/>
    <table style="border:0"  >
     <tr>
      <td align="center"><input type="button" value="Update" onclick="myAjaxCall()"  ><br/></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
 </s:form>
</s:div>
```

Then i have a jquery function named myAjaxCall() that looks like this. I am telling it to run an ajax function using json.

```
function myAjaxCall() {
    var url="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/storeCurrentStatusDialog.action?strid="+document.dform.strid.value+"&closingtime="+document.dform.closingtime.value+"&openingtime="+document.dform.openingtime.value+"&businessDt="+document.dform.businessDt.value+"&reason="+document.dform.reason.value;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(stringify(data));
    }});
```

}

The URL variable is being populated properly but my struts action is not being called. My first question is the dataType I am sending is json. WIll this automatically work. And the second question I have is how do I define my struts action in the struts.xml file for this to work. Something like this? The will return success.

```
    <action name="storeCurrentStatusDialog"
        class="com.mycompany.eposweb.action.StoreCurrentStatusAction"
        method="update">
        <result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

thanks

Comment: How did you check that an action isn't called? Also what is your action class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending data in json format better use `POST` method and serialize your form as below

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'storeCurrentStatusDialog.action',
    dataType:'json',
    data:$('#dform').serialize(),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(stringify(data));
    }});
```

You can find sample Struts2 action class and XML mapping [HERE](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/) for json

Comment: Can you help me with how I would deinfe my struts action in the xml as well please?

Comment: I think above link is enough for you